# Error when importing a data frame in .txt format where an extra column without a header appears

Tags: dataframe, matrix, import, network-protocols

?

I imported a data frame in .txt to Rstudio which is a matrix of interactions between animals (columns) and plants (rows). An error is occurring in the lines, which should be filling the first column of the data frame with the names of the plants, however instead there is a sequence of numbers from 1 to 11. In the original data there is no such information and the function I used to importing the .txt file was just right for this. What could be going on? How could I remove that first column?